# SELECT items from a databasefield divided by a comma

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, select

something I have been struggling with.

I have a tablefield in a database where I store multiple numbers, divided by a comma.

E.G. = TBL1 - Numberfield has (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

HOW can I show all rows from TBL1 where the Numberfield has 1 in it.

What i have rightnow works, but when I select 1, I also select 11, 12, ... how do I avoid this !

my code example:

```
WHERE        (tbl1.Numberfield LIKE '%' + @Numberfield + '%')
```

Ty for the help and your time !

Comment: Ugh.  This is why non-normalized schemas are bad.  Numberfield should instead be a child table, one row per number relating back to the parent row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's best to change your schema, but you can try this with your current schema:

```
WHERE  (',' + tbl1.Numberfield + ',' LIKE '%,' + @Numberfield + ',%')
```

Comment: This assumes there is no whitespace before or after any commas.